# gsutil not working with short lived access tokens

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, gsutil

We have been using gsutil to copy files onto GCS and it has been working fine.

We have shifted to use the short lived tokens for this purpose now. However, we notice that after authenticating the short lived tokens with gcloud , all gcloud commands are working fine, but gsutil is not working. Below is how we are using gsutil :

```
gcloud config set account d*****@****-dev.iam.gserviceaccount.com 
gcloud config set project *****
gcloud config set proxy/type http_no_tunnel
gcloud config set proxy/address *****
gcloud config set proxy/port 3128                    
gcloud config set auth/access_token_file ./target_token.json
gsutil cp ./airflow/*.py gs://d****-release
```

We get 401 error:

`ServiceException: 401 Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.create access to the Google Cloud Storage object. Permission 'storage.objects.create' denied on resource (or it may not exist).`

Comment: Are you sure the Service Account has the expected privileges : `storage.objects.create` ?

Comment: @MazlumTosun Yes, it does.

Comment: Based on your comment I changed my answer,check the revised answer which may help to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `gsutil config` command applies to users who have legacy stand-alone installations of gsutil. If you installed gsutil via the Cloud SDK, `gsutil config fails` unless you are specifically using the `-a flag` or have configured gcloud to not pass its managed credentials to gsutil (via the command `gcloud config set pass_credentials_to_gsutil false`).

Configure credentials for service accounts using the `-e flag`, try running the below command and authorize via the provided link (code that you need to paste back to the console) :

```
gsutil config -e
```

Refer to Google Cloud official documentation on [config - Obtain credentials and create configuration file](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/config) for more information

Check you may need to configure the application and save credentials in a `client_secrets.json` file and after the whole configuration and authentication process you will be able to use the gcloud/ gsutil command. Refer to official Google Cloud [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20service%20account,%2Fsa%2Dprivate%2Dkey.) for managing your secret key to create and authenticate your service account key.

Also check the OAuth access token has expired and you may need to be refreshed. This can be avoided by refreshing the access token early, but code can also catch this error, refresh the token and retry automatically.

Check the OAuth access token's bound project does not match the project associated with the provided developer key.

You can check detailed reasons for [401- Unauthorized](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/status-codes#401_Unauthorized) for more information.

**EDIT:**
Google APIs use [OAuth 2.0 protocol](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749) for authentication and authorization. SAs are used to create GCP OAuth 2.0 Access Tokens using gcloud CLI or APIs.

IAM Roles are not assigned to tokens, assigned to the account member ID.These permissions will be valid for any OAuth Token that is created by the SA unless limited by scopes. When you are generating Oauth access tokens you can modify the scopes and write your own code while making token requests.

Refer to [Bastien Cadiot-Medium blog, How to generate and use temporary credentials on GCP](https://medium.com/wescale/how-to-generate-and-use-temporary-credentials-on-google-cloud-platform-b425ef95a00d) and [Tanuj Bolisetty - Medium blog, How to impersonate Service Accounts in GCP](https://medium.com/@tanujbolisetty/gcp-impersonate-service-accounts-36eaa247f87c) for more information.

Comment: We want to use OAuth2. Without any manual intervention, we want to execute our pipeline, where we want to pass the short lived SA token. but the `-e` option will not make it manual.

Comment: Please check the EDIT in the answer, which may help to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, and resolved it by simply using the correct gsutil path. From the docs,

> If you try to authenticate gsutil using the gcloud init command, but are still not able to access the expected buckets or objects, your system might have both the legacy, stand-alone version of gsutil and the Google Cloud CLI-bundled version of gsutil installed on it. Run the command gsutil version -l and check the value for using cloud sdk. If False, your system is using the stand-alone version of gsutil when you run commands. It's recommended that you remove the stand-alone version of gsutil from your system; however, you can alternatively authenticate using the gsutil config command.

when running `gsutil version -l`, I saw `using cloud sdk: False`. I targeted the gsutil installed within my gcp sdk installation, and it started working perfectly. It was located within [gcp sdk location]/bin/gsutil